# How do I plot a unstacked bar graph with a my dataframe structure?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to plot an unstacked bar chart for pairs of products differentiated by the year. I.e. what is the difference in X for product 1 between 2020 and 2021?

I have a challenging dataframe structure and thus not sure how I can shape it to fit Plotly's unstacked bar chart framework? I hope someone can guide.Thanks

dataframe:

```
Date | Shoes__sale_x | Category_x | Shoes__sale_y | Category_y
Jan  |  $20            | 2020       |  $25           | 2021
Feb  |  $24            | 2020       |  $75           | 2021
```

I want the bar chart to look like this where the legend would display the Category (i.e. 2020 or 2021). How would I best do this?

[image]

Comment: If you use `plotly` remove the `seaborn` tag, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import plotly.express as px
df_sub = df.melt(id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['Shoes__sale_x', 'Shoes__sale_y'], var_name='sales')
df_sub['value'] = df_sub['value'].str[1:].astype(int)
fig = px.bar(df_sub, x="Date", y="value", color='sales', barmode='group', height=600)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title='Price', title='Chart Title')
fig.show()
```

`Plot`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. structure your data frame with **pandas** `wide_to_long()`
2. use plotly express to generate from structured data

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Date | Shoes__sale_x | Category_x | Shoes__sale_y | Category_y
Jan  |  $20            | 2020       |  $25           | 2021
Feb  |  $24            | 2020       |  $75           | 2021"""), sep="\s+\|\s+", engine="python")

df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=["Shoes__sale_", "Category_"], i="Date", j="Sale", suffix=r'\w+').reset_index()
df2["Shoes__sale_"] = df2["Shoes__sale_"].str.strip("$").astype(float)

px.bar(df2, x="Date", y="Shoes__sale_", color="Sale", hover_data=["Category_"], barmode="group")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help! really appreciate it. I am not sure where the j="Sale" comes from as I dont have a column "Sales" in my df. Can you clarify please?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html take a look at `df2` it's the name of the column that contains the right hand side of the stub